# How to generate enums in a F# Type Provider

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-3.0

[This changeset to the F# 3.0 sample pack](http://fsharp3sample.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/20278) seems to suggest it's possible, but there is no ProvidedEnum in ProvidedTypes.fs

Answer (score 3):

Use `ProvidedTypeDefinition` and just use a real enum type as the base type.  This feature isn't especially well tested, so ask follow-up questions if you run into problems.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you. Let's say I want to generate a new enum with three values A, B, and C. What enum do I pass to the base type if it doesn't exist yet? Should I create dummy enums inside the type provider with several arities, like Func<> and Action<>?

Comment: @ovatsus - you need to have a real enum that you can repurpose (perhaps a dummy enum that you reuse for all provided enums; unfortunately all F# enums must have at least one value, in contrast to C#).  To be honest, I didn't expect provided enums to work at all, so the limitation doesn't surprise me too much.

Comment: I tried your approach (using a dummy enum as a base type) and it somewhat worked...but not really; the generated type while reported be an enum via reflection (typeof<MySyntheticEnum>.IsEnum = true) the type does not really behave as an enum. For example: the "x" in let x = MySyntheticEnum.SomeLabel is inferred to be an int, not something of type MySyntheticEnum. The type has other bizarre features as well...